# Remove specific text separated with comma

Tags: windows, notepad++, find-and-replace

I have srt file containing following text

```
1
00:00:06,139 --> 00:00:07,140
F/6.3, SS 800, ISO 200, EV 0, GPS (76.2463, 25.7251, 16), D 93.74m, H 35.00m, H.S 2.09m/s, V.S 0.10m/s

2
00:00:07,140 --> 00:00:08,141
F/6.3, SS 800, ISO 200, EV 0, GPS (76.2463, 25.7251, 16), D 91.28m, H 34.80m, H.S 2.82m/s, V.S 0.50m/s

3
00:00:08,141 --> 00:00:09,142
F/6.3, SS 800, ISO 200, EV 0, GPS (76.2463, 25.7251, 16), D 88.47m, H 34.60m, H.S 2.94m/s, V.S 0.00m/s

4
00:00:09,142 --> 00:00:10,143
F/6.3, SS 800, ISO 200, EV 0, GPS (76.2463, 25.7250, 16), D 85.39m, H 34.70m, H.S 3.54m/s, V.S 0.00m/s
```

I want to keep only below format and delete every thig from srt file using notepad++

```
4
00:00:09,142 --> 00:00:10,143
GPS (76.2463, 25.7250, 16)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `F/6.+(GPS \(.+\)).+`
- Replace with: `$1`
- Search mode: Regular expression

[image: Result]